# why is a white ball rendering in my scene?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am using the bps rig, but I already animated with the character. Does any one know how to make it go away with out harming the animation? Oh btw i used the most recent bps tutorial.

Comment: If you could please provide a picture or gif of the problem, I might be able to figure it out. Hope I can help!

Comment: Are you using the Black Plasma rig? This happened to me too, and I fixed it by deleting the character and appending a new one. They aren't a pain to set up but if you have already animated it there might be a problem. **Please provide more information in your question, e.g. what tutorials you followed, what rig you used, etc.**

Comment: As said above, if you are using the black plasma rig, then you can delete the character and append it again. If it doesn't work, just ask bps on their discord server.